# Crop circular shape from UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, crop

I would like to crop circular shape from `UIImage` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is the code

```
-(UIImage *)croppedImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(Width(self.cropperImageView), Width(self.cropperImageView)), NO, 0.0);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGFloat scaleFactorX = Width(self.photoImageView) / self.photoImageView.image.size.width;
        CGFloat scaleFactorY = Height(self.photoImageView) / self.photoImageView.image.size.height;
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddArc(context, Width(self.cropperImageView) / 2, Width(self.cropperImageView) / 2, Width(self.cropperImageView) / 2, 0, 2 * M_PI, 0);
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextClip(context);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        [self.photoImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(Left(self.cropperImageView), Right(self.cropperImageView), Width(self.cropperImageView), Width(self.cropperImageView))];

        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return image;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What's the result with your code?

Comment: this is the result http://prntscr.com/csfein

Comment: @Larme any thought?